# How to add an extension name to a codeigniter route

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there anyway to put an extension name to a codeigniter route, for example like (.html, .php), ive read the documention about routing and is seems that they dont have that kind of feature.

i just want my route to look like this

```
https://localhost/project/route.php
```

any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just modify this in `config.php`.

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '.html'; //or .php
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in your application/config/config.php file.

I copy/past my config :

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URL suffix
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to add a suffix to all URLs generated by CodeIgniter.
| For more information please see the user guide:
|
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
*/

$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';
```

EDIT : [the doc](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)